# oracle pl/saql ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT SUM(SALES_AMOUNT)SALES,
YEAR,
MONTH,
CATAGORY_ID,
SALES_PERSON_ID,
ITEM_TYPE_ID
FROM APEX_FINAL
    where sales_amount is not null
     and catagory_id is not null
GROUP BY (YEAR,MONTH,CATAGORY_ID,SALES_PERSON_ID,ITEM_TYPE_ID)

union all

SELECT SUM(SALES_AMOUNT)SALES,
YEAR,
MONTH,
CATAGORY_ID,
'all others' SALES_PERSON_ID,
ITEM_TYPE_ID
FROM APEX_FINAL
    where sales_amount is not null
    and sales_person_id is null 
GROUP BY (YEAR,MONTH,CATAGORY_ID,SALES_PERSON_ID,ITEM_TYPE_ID)
```

this is my code plz help me in resolving my problem as i m getting the eroor of mis math data types but all data types are same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sales Person ID seems to have the mismatch. It could possibly be a `NUMERIC` datatype in your table.

May be you can use `TO_CHAR(SALES_PERSON_ID)` in the first Union Query as below. It would help you solve the issue

```
SELECT SUM(SALES_AMOUNT)SALES,
YEAR,
MONTH,
CATAGORY_ID,
TO_CHAR(SALES_PERSON_ID) SALES_PERSON_ID,
ITEM_TYPE_ID
FROM APEX_FINAL
    where sales_amount is not null
     and catagory_id is not null
GROUP BY (YEAR,MONTH,CATAGORY_ID,SALES_PERSON_ID,ITEM_TYPE_ID)

union all

SELECT SUM(SALES_AMOUNT)SALES,
YEAR,
MONTH,
CATAGORY_ID,
'all others' SALES_PERSON_ID,
ITEM_TYPE_ID
FROM APEX_FINAL
    where sales_amount is not null
    and sales_person_id is null 
GROUP BY (YEAR,MONTH,CATAGORY_ID,SALES_PERSON_ID,ITEM_TYPE_ID)
```

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling hours on a similar issue and realized that the column orders of the two tables we are unioning should be the same!

It still gives you the same error, so make sure columns are in the same order :)

Comment: THANK YOU, faced the same error and this actually solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

As @Nisha already pointed out, you're probably getting this error because `SALES_PERSON_ID` is a numeric field - you'll either have to convert it to a string or (preferably) join to another table to get the name of the sales person.

Additionally, I believe you've got a logic error in your query - in your first `SELECT`, you filter by `catagory_person_id is not null`; this should probably be `sales_person_id is not null`.

Assuming this is the case, then you can simplify the query with a `CASE` statement (you could also use `DECODE` or `COALESCE`):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(SALES_AMOUNT) SALES,
  YEAR,
  MONTH,
  CATAGORY_ID,
  (case 
     when sales_person_id is not null then to_char(SALES_PERSON_ID)
     else 'all others' 
   end) as sales_person_id,
  ITEM_TYPE_ID
FROM APEX_FINAL
where sales_amount is not null
GROUP BY (YEAR,MONTH,CATAGORY_ID,SALES_PERSON_ID,ITEM_TYPE_ID)
```